# Use arcpy to check whether feature class geometry has ZM

Tags: arcpy, geometry, 3d, describe-object

I am looking for a programmatic way using arcpy to determine whether or not a feature class (FC) has Z and/or M geometry. It's easy enough to get the geometry type using the code below, but this just tells me the base type (point, line, polygon) and does not have details about ZM. I would rather not have to create a cursor and read the actual feature geometries (it should not be necessary, since the entire FC must have the same geometry).

```
import arcpy
desc = arcpy.Describe("D:\\MyData\\Scratch.gdb\\polyzm")
geometryType = desc.shapeType
print geometryType
```

which returns this result:

```
Polygon
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Describe object also has [the hasM and hasZ properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/FeatureClass_properties/018v00000011000000/) which:

> Indicates if the geometry is m-value enabled

and

> Indicates if the geometry is z-value enabled

respectively.